# Double buffering swt

Tags: java, swt

I'm creating simple app i have `Tree` object where i store filenames when user choose one `SWTImageCanvas.loadImage(path)` is being called. Every image has some points defined so points are displayed as `gc.fillOval`. When user move mouse over oval it name is being displayed i achive this by setting some additional variable and using `SWTImageCanvas.redraw()` method. Such redrawing cause blinking of canvas so i thought about double buffering i have read some tutorials about it but when i'm trying to run it my image is hovered by white layer with ovalls on it here is my drawing function

```
    private void drawStations(Event e) {
Rectangle clientRect = mainSWTImageCanvas.getClientArea();
        if(mainSWTImageCanvas.getSourceImage()!=null)
            {
                if(mainSWTImageCanvas.getScreenImage()!=null)
                    mainSWTImageCanvas.getScreenImage().dispose();
                Image screenImage = new Image(mainSWTImageCanvas.getDisplay(),clientRect.width,clientRect.height);
                this.gc = new GC(screenImage);
        //drawing ovals on gc
       .
       .
       .
        this.gc.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0);
                this.gc.dispose();
                e.gc.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that double buffering in swt `display` can by done by passing `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` in constructor.